# CSS - Have children to fit parent, and have their content as min-width

Tags: html, css

```
<ul style="width:100%;height:50px;">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar foo</li>
    <li>bar bar bar bar bar barbarbar</li>
</ul>
```

I want my li to be horizontally aligned, to fill the ul in width, to have their text as min-width, and if they are too big horizontally for the container to overflow (not go to line).

Any solution ?

Comment: You should hire a developer in these cases, it's like nobody should work "for free".
Provide us with more code, or at least a JSFiddle in order to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You have just add some CSS as shown below

```
ul{background:#dddddd;}

ul li{
   float:left;
   list-style:square inside;
   padding-right:20px;
   line-height:50px;
}
```

[Here is Output.](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepvirani/esZpH/1/)

Comment: works apart from the fact that eccessive long <li> go to line instead of staying in one line and overflowing out of the ul (and the window)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7QRwj/)**</kbd>

you can use `flexbox`

css

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    /*justify-content: center; if you want to justify flex elements*/
}
li {
    min-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**EDIT :** `min-width` for contents of `li`  <kbd>**[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7QRwj/1/)**</kbd>

For more on [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: you set min-width:100px, I want min-width to be the contents of each li

Comment: I have added a new demo.

Comment: Better, but now li's go over eachother when their are too large for the ul, while I want them to keep staying side by side and overflowing on the right of the ul
maybe it can be done in JS only

Comment: for that you need to give width to `li`